# Using #define for a function

Tags: c++, macros

After struggling with C++ typedef and define, I've tried myself some code and here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define sub(a,b) a-b
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout <<  n*sub(5*2,3*3)+1;
}
```

I've find that if `n=3`, it'll give `22` and the equation is
`3*5*2-3*3+1=22;`

I can't imagine the mechanism of it, can someone help me please?

Comment: `#define sub(a,b) a-b` -> `#define sub(a,b) ((a)-(b))`, but really the best option is to not use a macro.

Comment: `#define` is a preprocessor directive and does pure text replacement. It does not evaluate the arguments that are passed. So your equation turns into `n*5*2-3*3`

Comment: Rule No.1 *always enclose your macros inside brackets `()`*

Comment: Rule no. 0 - don't use macros unless absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1):

Just insert in this expression

```
n*sub(5*2,3*3)+1
```

the macro extension  `5*2 - 3*3` and you will have

```
n * 5*2 - 3*3 + 1
```

You should rewrite the macro at least like

```
#define sub(a,b) ( (a ) - ( b ) )
```

And in C++ it is better to use inline functions (possibly with the specifier `constexpr`) instead pf such a macro.